# How can I use SHDocVw in C# form?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a program that checks if the address in a web browser isn't a 404
I searched in google how to do it and I found a tutorial.
In the tutorial there's a namespace called `SHDocVw`.
Visual C# tells me `the namespace 'SHDocVw' could not be found`.
What I need to do to fix this?

Comment: It is an HTTP error code.  For a website however it is just another web page.  With an unpredictable URL.

Answer (score 4):

Totally agreed that you should not use `SHDocVw` to test if a url is returning a 404.  You should use a web client.  Do not use `SHDocVw` for that.

But, if like me, you're googling `SHDocVw` for other reasons *like controlling the IE browser window from your app* and come across this post...

To add SHDocVw:

In Visual Studio, go to add a reference and browse to

> c:\windows\system\shdocvw.dll

or

> c:\windows\system32\shdocvw.dll

This will add a reference to `Interop.SHDocVw` to your project.

Comment: Coming at you 4 years in the future; I'm so glad that you had added this section

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that.

Instead, use the `WebClient` class:

```
try {
    new WebClient().DownloadData(url);
} catch (WebException ex) {
    //Bad! Waah!
}
```